# How to read file after uploading to server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have set up some HTML to take in a file, and the file is sent to the server.  However, I don't want the data to be on server but rather the client.  How can I send the data back to the client side while still being able to read the data?  This will have to be compatible with IE8 or at least IE9.  I am using Javascript and KnockoutJS for the client side, and using C#/asp.net MVC for server side.

This is how I am sending the file to the server.  Since this is a POST Method, shouldn't I be able to return something?  Maybe I don't understand how it is supposed to be use.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("loadReport", "home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"})){ 

 <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />}


    public ActionResult loadReport()
    {
        foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
        {
            //     if (!Request.Files[upload].HasFile()) continue;
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
            Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, filename));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName));
        }
        return this.Json(new { });
    }
```

These two parts are essentially parts that I found on a blog on how to upload to the server.  Instead of returning a JSON file, they returned a view.  I tried this to check the functionality of it, but it returned a new page rather than a json file to my javascript.

Comment: Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Are you able to receive and may be save the stream on the server side ?

Comment: What do you mean by receiving and saving the stream on the server side?

Comment: You are trying to send a file to the server(step1).
And them resend back to the client (step2).
Is the step 1 working ?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file to the server, it stays on the server; you cannot read it via the client unless 
1.) When rendering the page, the file's content is read on the server side and displayed. 
2.) Use AJAX to fetch the file's content; then, use JavaScript to manipulate the result. 
 
So, save the file; then, use AJAX to retrieve its content or refresh the page and write the file's content to the rendering page. 
 
Hope this explanation is clear and it helps.

Comment: When saving the file, how can I save it without having the page refresh on me?

Comment: you'll have to use AJAX for that. Use [this link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Upload-Files-Asynchronously-829691df) and [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwZ6zdu3TMM) as tutorials.